# ¿Cómo graficar dos variables en un dataframe usando scatterplot?

Tags: python

Hola tengo los siguientes datos guardados en un dataframe:

```
letra    numero     valor 
  0         1        12 
  0         2        15
  0         3        16
  1         1        15
  1         2        20
  1         3        15
  2         1        13
  2         2        14
  2         3        12
  3         1        17
  3         2        16
  3         3        17
```

Como podria selecionar en las filas para graficar un plot de la siguiente forma:
para el valor de 1 de la columna "numero" que me grafique las coordenadas letra vs. valor o sea en este caso (0,12),para siguiente valor 1 las coordenadas (0,15) y asi sucesivamente con todos los valores de 1 en una curva, los mismo para los valores de 2 en otra curva y luego 3 en otra curva.
Mi archivo es muy largo tiene 2400 filas para ese caso ¿Qué podría hacer?
¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un `for` para crear varios `Dataframes` y a partir de estos poder seccionar por número y crear las gráficas letra vs valor que necesitas, aquí el código:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

#Crear el DF

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letra' : [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'numero' : [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
    'valor' : [12,15,16,15,20,15,13,14,12,17,16,17]
    })

# Ordenar por número
df.sort_values(by=['numero'])

#Conocer la longitud
longitud = len(df['numero'].unique())
print(longitud)

#Iterar DF por nímero y crear graficos
for val in range(1,longitud+1):
    val = df.loc[df['numero'] == val]
    #val.plot.scatter(x='letra', y='valor')
    plot.plot(val['letra'], val['valor'])
    plot.title('Gráfico Letra vs. Valor {}'.format(val['numero'].unique()))
    plot.xlabel('Letra')
    plot.ylabel('Valor')
    plot.show()
```

Adjunto la salida como imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como te comentaron arriba puedes usar directo `scatterplot` de pandas ( la linea que te comente en el for), pero te dará puntos, no curvas. Por lo cual decidí usar la librería matplotlib llamando `plot`. Checa las gráficas y usa lo que más te convenga.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido mucho

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar scatterplot de pandas de la siguiente forma:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='letra', y='valor')
```